# Why Laravel returns 1 as user id in blade?

Tags: laravel

I want to use user ID in blade templates to restrict some rights. After several unsuccessful attempts, I output the user ID via `{{ Auth::user()->id }}`

For all new users, the ID always returns "1", but the email `{{ Auth::user()->email }}` is returned correct. What could be the problem?

And User ID "1" does not exist in the database at all

dump and die User:

```
    User {#650 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "users"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:19 [▼
    "id" => true
  ]
  #original: array:19 [▼
    "id" => 106
  ]
  #changes: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}
```

But if I log in with my account:

```
User {#650 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "users"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:19 [▼
    "id" => 2
  ]
  #original: array:19 [▼
    "id" => 2
  ]
  #changes: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}
```

User class:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Sorry for wasting time, I'm an idiot. In the controller, instead of comparing, I was assigning a new value to the user->id variable

Comment: do you try Auth::id(); ?

Comment: Yes, but it still returns "1"  instead of "106"

Comment: Did you modify the user model?

Comment: @jewishmoses No, the model has not been edited

Comment: What the output of `dd(Auth::user());` where you expect the correct ID ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier in #attributes: array:19 [▼
    "id" => true AND #original: array:19 [▼
    "id" => 106

Comment: My best guesses is that you do somewhere `if(Auth::user()->id = $bool)` or in your model you cast the property `protected $casts = ['id' => 'boolean'];` but it's hard to guess what's happening without your code.

Comment: Sorry for wasting time, I'm an idiot. In the controller, instead of comparing, I was assigning a new value to the user->id variable

Comment: You're not ;) That kind of mistakes happens to anyone

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these ?

```
Auth()->id();
auth()->id();
```

Also try to mention some part of your code too or give some exapmle.

[read more on authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)